# classes 'disappearing' from rendered HTML on WordPress custom page template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to dynamically create HTML based on nested array data and I almost have it working. The php script I have written seems to work (it creates correctly tagged HTML) but when the page renders the classes are not included in the rendered HTML.

Here is a sample of the array data:

```
[["This","DT"],["is","VBZ"],["your","PRP$"],["first","JJ"],["post","NN"],[".","."]]
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($decoded as $element) {
    $text = $element[0];
    $tag = $element[1];
    // if text is punctuation, do not add class
    $punct = array(".", ",", ";", ":", "!", "?", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "'", "`", "\"");
    if (in_array ( $text , $punct)){
        $span = ("<span>" . $text . "</span>");
    }
    else{ // add class and a space 
        $span = ("<span class='" . $tag . "'> " . $text . "</span>");
    }
    echo $span;
}
```

To be clear, the spans in the source code have the classes, but the rendered elements do not.

Source code:

```
<span class='DT'> This</span><span class='VBZ'> is</span><span class='PRP$'> your</span><span class='JJ'> first</span><span class='NN'> post</span><span>.</span>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<span>This</span>
<span>is</span>
<span>your</span>
<span>first</span>
<span>post.</span>
```

Is there a way to 'force' the classes to be rendered? 
Alternatively, is there a more effective approach to accomplish the same end?

Screenshots:

Sources tab:
[image]

Elements tab:
[image]

Comment: I am confused, how is source different from rendered. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: How do you inspect the "source code" and the "rendered result"?

Comment: I am using Chrome developer tools. 
By source, I mean the code seen in the 'elements' tab
By rendered, I mean the code seen in the 'sources' tab
Just checked in Firefox/firebug and the same results occur.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "rendered HTML". If the tags show up in the source code, your code works. Could you add screenshots to your question that show the problem?

Comment: Thanks Gerald, it seems my reputation wasn't high enough to directly post the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Running the following snippet in PhpFiddle (I just combined your two pieces of code into one), you get the expected output.

```
<?php
foreach ([["This","DT"],["is","VBZ"],["your","PRP$"],["first","JJ"],["post","NN"],[".","."]] as $element) {
    $text = $element[0];
    $tag = $element[1];
    // if text is punctuation, do not add class
    $punct = array(".", ",", ";", ":", "!", "?", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "'", "`", "\"");
    if (in_array ( $text , $punct)){
        $span = ("<span>" . $text . "</span>");
    }
    else{ // add class and a space 
        $span = ("<span class='" . $tag . "'> " . $text . "</span>");
    }
    echo $span;
}
?>
```

Both viewing the source and inspecting the elements show the classes are present.

If you're wanting them to be rendered differently, you need to add CSS rules to go along with the classes.  Everything is working correctly in the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks michael, that is odd. 
Would it make a difference that I am working in WordPress?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress so I couldn't comment on if they do any pre-processing to pages.  Can you further elaborate on the problem? Are you saying that styles aren't being applied to those elements?

Comment: There aren't any styling rules for the classes. I'll add them and see if this changes the results.

Comment: No, the styling rules made no change. 
I do see that outside WordPress the HTML renders with the classes no problem.

Comment: Yes, I just did a quick test myself in Chrome as well.  This seems to be WordPress specific.  Sorry I couldn't offer more help.  I'm not familiar with WordPress myself, so it's possible there's some type of pre-processing happening in WordPress that is somehow removing classes

Comment: Thank you @michael for the response. I will see if I can find out about pre-processing that WordPress is doing that might strip the classes off.

Comment: You might want to check out this post:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-does-wp-sometimes-strip-class-and-id-from-html#post-1145674

Perhaps since you're using single quotes instead of double quotes around the classes, WordPress is identifying this as invalid attributes and removing them? (Note: single quotes are totally okay under the HTML5 specification, but maybe WordPress is using it's own set of rules when enforcing "valid" HTML?)